# Dynamic float left UL inside a float left DIV

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm trying to achieve to following behavior:

On a `Search Results` site, I have two containers.

`Container 1` and `Container 2` are `DIV` with `float: left` property.

Inside `Container 2` is an `UL` with a variable amount of `LI` elements.

[image]

`Container 1` is only visible if search returned matching entries.
So it can happen that `Container 1` is not present in the HTML at all.

In that case I want `Container 2` to be full width and the `LI` elements to be `float: left`

[image]

Or if the width of the view port (responsive layout) can't fit in both containers, `Container 2` collapses to a new row. In that case I also want `Container 2` to be full width an the `LI` elements to be `float: left`

[image]

When I simply set the `LI` to `float: left` the whole `Container 2` already collapses to a new row. Also when trying to alternatively set the `LI` to `display: inline-block` etc. `Container 2` collapses.

Do you know of an elegant way to solve this with CSS? I tried several approaches, but it doesn't work.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y8vctgun/1/

Comment: When you say not present in the html you mean that it's not there completely or it's does not take up any space because it does not have any elements inside?

Comment: @nejc.m It does not have any elements inside at that moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if the container1 is completely removed from the html when no results are present then you can do this in CSS like so...

```
.container1 + .container2 li {
    float: none!Important;
}

.container2 ul li {
    float: left;

    margin-right: 20px;
    padding: 4px;
    background-color: #0f0;
    color: #000;
 }
```

So to explain. I added float:left to the li item and then if container1 is present I override it with float:none. Adjust it to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It works if `Container 1` is removed. I can modify the Search Results script to do this. But this doesn't solve the problem when `Container 2` collapses due to view port width. But I guess I can use a `Media Query` in that case.